# Error while installing HomeBrew - "error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403"

Tags: git, macos, homebrew, http-status-code-403

I am trying to install HomeBrew on my mac (Big Sur) and running into issue. See the screenshot below for details

```
user@Machine-Name ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R user:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
Evaluating command /usr/sbin/chown...
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
fatal: expected flush after ref listing
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
user@Machine-Name ~ %
```

Additional info : I had successfully installed homebrew earlier. I had it uninstalled and am trying to install again.

My analysis
It looked like git credentials error, i read that one needs to set the email id which i did but it still did not help. This is a blocker for me as I need to install my python environment for a project. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have configured credentials in `~/.gitconfig` or in `~/.config/git/config` ?